# How can clone database in mariadb prompt character?

Tags: mariadb, copy

```
mysqlword="wwww"
old="xxxx"
new="yyyy"
mysqldump $old  -u root -p$mysqlword   | mysql $new  -u root -p$mysqlword
```

Now new database was cloned as like old database.
Can i use some command to clone database when entering mariadb terminal?

```
mysql -u root -pwwww
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6
Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

How can clone database in mariadb prompt character instead of inputing `mysqldump $old  -u root -p$mysqlword   | mysql $new  -u root -p$mysqlword` in bash terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General answer - No!

First of all - mysqldump it is not a simple sql command, this is
    complicated logic behind it, such as:
 - show definition of all objects - tables, routings, foreign keys
 - manage export import in proper order, like disable constraints and etc

Second (in addition to first) - mysql console (and SQL as language) do not support database level commands, like select all - You would need do this for each tables, objects, routines.

Federated engine (FederatedX) also not resolve "problem"